# Using SSH with shell script works with manual input but not with parameters

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting

I have a shell script `authenticate.sh` that looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p '$1' ssh $2@localhost
```

I call it using

```
bash authenticate.sh password username
```

But I get "Permission denied, please try again" when I run it. If I instead run

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@localhost
```

it works...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The single apostrophes must have just thrown the script off, see note below.

This works as intended:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "$1" ssh "$2"@localhost
```

This is because single apostrophes do not allow any variables expanded inside.